# Session issue in Cakephp 2x version

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I am facing some weird issue related with session , when i set debug to 0 , session stop working in entire application and when i set it to 2 then sessions works fine.

I don't know what is going wrong , any help would be appreciated !!

Thanks

Comment: CakePHP is just PHP code. Diagnose the usual stuff: errors, warnings and notices; HTTP headers; cookies; session files...

Comment: It's more likely that you don't see the issue when debug=0 and therefore don't notice that session is broken